# Prove $(x-a)^{d/2} + (x+a)^{d/2}\geq 2x^{d/2}$ for $x\geq a$

Tags: inequality

I have reached the following inequality while solving a physics problem and was wondering if this is true.

Let $d\geq 2$ be an integer, and let $0<a\in\mathbb{R}$. I want to find out that if $x\geq a$, then
$$
(x-a)^{d/2} + (x+a)^{d/2}\geq 2x^{d/2}
$$
Several arbitrary attempts in Wolfram Alpha suggest this is true. So I went on to compute the derivative, but then realized that differentiating will reduce the problem to the same inequality, just with $\frac{d-2}{2}$ instead of $\frac{d}{2}$.

Any other method to solve this? Maybe it is not true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function $f(x)=x^{d/2}$ is convex. Now you can apply Jensen's inequality.

$$\frac{f(x-a)+f(x+a)}2\ge f\left(\frac{(x-a)+(x+a)}2\right)$$

Comment: nice1 man, +1 for sure.

Comment: @A.Molendijk "man" is pretty presumptuous.

Comment: I'm a man, after all, so no problem :)